# Add Conditional Transactional Behavior In Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, transactions

In oracle 10g, I have one stored procedure per table per operation (insert, select, update, delete). Actually there can be multiple procedures per table per operation, for example in case of select it can be SelectList, SelectOneRecord, Search (with dynamic query).

None of these procedures have transactions.

Sometimes I have to combine multiple operations in a transaction. For example insert in one table and update in another table, all in one transaction. For this I make a separate procedure which has transaction. This procedure then call the two procedures.

To enable the above combination-of-procedure-calls-in-single-transaction, I do not put any transaction behavior in the procedures, as discussed above.

Most of the time I have to perform only one operation, such as insert in one table. Since the insert procedure do not have transaction behavior therefore I have to make a separate procedure that have transaction behavior and that procedure call the insert procedure.

I end up with lots of basic procedures (one table, one operation) and lots of transaction procedures that are basically wrappers around basic procedures.

My question is, is there some way to have conditional transactional behavior in the basic procedures. By this I mean that some if-condition where I can put the transaction logic, so that the transaction behavior can be on or off based on some parameter that I pass. Then when I want to do only one operation, such as insert in a table, I call the basic procedure with transaction behavior; and when I want to call two procedures in a transaction, such as insert in one table and update in another table all in one transaction, then I make a separate transaction procedure and call the two basic procedure without transaction behavior.

The following is a transaction procedure that call another procedure and wrap it in a transaction:

```
BEGIN
    SAVEPOINT the_start;

    BasicProcedure(<list of parameters>);

    COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN

         BEGIN
             ROLLBACK TO the_start;
             RAISE;
         END;
END;
```

I can very well put the savepoint line and the commit line in if-statements, but can I also put the exception block in a if-statement. Do I have to put the exception block in if-statement? What if I catch exception in procedure, would it automatically rollback when exception comes?

Comment: Any reason why you haven't accepted APC's answer? If so, why not say so, and invite alternative answers?

Answer (score 6):

What you have written is called a Table API.  Some people swear by them, others anathematize them.   The case for Table APIs is basically: modularity and code reuse.  The case against is primarily performance: they encourage row by row or table by table processing, when a bespoke SQL join would be more efficient.

Personally I have stood on both sides of the fence.  Currently I favour tailored code: it makes transactions easier to work with.

Which brings me to your situation.  Table APIs are supposed to be generic and usable in all situations.  That means they cannot control the management of transactions: that properly belongs to the programs which call the Table API methods.  These programs are the code which implements the business logic: a business transaction consists of a number of activities which constitute a Unit Of Work.  All of these have to succeed in order for the transaction to succeed, otherwise the business transaction needs to be rolled back.  If the Table API commands issue their own commits, a subsequent failure would leave the business transaction in an inconsistent state.  [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) applies at this level as well as the individual SL level.

This is actually no different from writing stored procedures with bespoke SQL in them.

---

> "it's unclear to me if you're advocating making the business logic
>   transactions stored procedures."

This is a large area to cover, and there's more to design PL/SQL applications than business logic.  (If you have access to a time machine you should travel back to Open World 2009 to catch my presentation on "Designing PL/SQL with Intent")

But broadly, yes, the outward-facing aspect of the PL/SQL layer should consist of business logic APIs, organised around Units of Work i.e. business transactions.

> "such procedures be autonomous transactions? "

Absolutely not.  Autonomous transactions are fit for only one purpose: logging and auditing of activity, where we need a permanent record of what occurred without affecting the wider transaction.  Any other use of that pragma is a kludge or a data corruption bug waiting to happen.

Business transactions are transactions pure and simple.  Either the stored procedures should own the commit or else they should defer it to the calling program.

Comment: how do you mean by 'tailored code' - table API for each table instead of a generic one?

Comment: @APC: Thoughtful response, but it's unclear to me if you're advocating making the business logic transactions stored procedures. It would seem a good idea to do so. Do you agree, and should such procedures be autonomous transactions?

Comment: @APC: Very thorough, and I'd agree with you on both points. You've got my vote. I'd have loved to have seen your presentation. At least Oracle, unlike postgres, let's you set the isolation level of a stored procedure, to better match the operations to the intent of the unit of work.